# VB.Net Using Quote Mark in Quote Marks

Tags: vb.net, quote

I want to create a text from texts. I'll show you the code.

```
"text"" + textbox1.text + """
```

And I want it to out like this

```
text"textbox1.text"
```

But It gives me errors because of the using quote marks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
"text" & Chr(34) & textbox1.text & Chr(34)
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be this?

```vb
"text""" + textbox1.text + """"
```

If I remember correctly a double double quote is how to escape a quote in VB.

In C# this would have been

```cs
"text\"" + textbox1.Text + "\""
// or (with a verbatim string)
@"text""" + textbox1.text + @""""
// more logic use of verbatim string (especially if you 
// want to create a string with multiple lines)
string.Format(@"text""{0}""", textbox1.Text);
```

\" means the double quote character in a string in C#

"" means the double quote character in a string in VB or in a C# verbatim string

*In a verbatim string the \ doesn't escape anymore so to have a quote inside a verbatim string you also have to double it like in VB.Net
(worded differently, VB.Net string are all verbatim strings)*